# How to loop through this JSON? I have tried the following js but it gives the error which I have mentioned below

Tags: json

```js
function searchMarks(srchMarksFrom,srchMarksTo){
 
 alert("search marks called: "+srchMarksFrom+ " "+srchMarksTo);
 
 $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"searchForMarks.htm",
  data: {
   "srchMarksFrom" : srchMarksFrom,
   "srchMarksTo": srchMarksTo
  },
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
   
  $.each(data,function(i,value){

   alert(studOnMarks.i.id);
  });
   
  },
  error: function(){
   alert("ajax failure");
  }, 
 });
 
 
 
}//end of search me
```

```html
this is the json response

{
  "studOnMarks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Rajan",
      "tenthmarks": 70,
      "dob": "1990-01-17",
      "phone": 9743473763
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "subhasish",
      "tenthmarks": 78,
      "dob": "1989-06-19",
      "phone": 9743473763
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "ani",
      "tenthmarks": 90,
      "dob": "1991-12-20",
      "phone": 9743473763
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to iterate through this json response. I tried the above js but it gives:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '252' in {"studOnMarks":[{"id":1,"name":"Rajan","tenthmarks":70,"dob":"1990-01-17","phone":9743473763},{"id":2,"name":"subhasish","tenthmarks":78,"dob":"1989-06-19","phone":9743473763},{"id":3,"name":"ani","tenthmarks":90,"dob":"1991-12-20","phone":9743473763}]}
I need to access each id, name and so on. Please help

Comment: You have to **parse** the JSON first: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196. Also `studOnMarks.i.id` won't work.

Comment: I tried this:
$.each(data.studOnMarks, function(index, element) {
  alert(element.id); 
  });
it gives the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Again, you have to parse the JSON first.

Comment: I have tried the usual ways and looked into the solutions. Please dont mark it as duplicate. @Felix Kling

Comment: But it *is* a duplicate. Did you thoroughly read through the answer? What you posted in the comment works, if you do `data = JSON.parse(data);` first.